# ASP.net oncheckedchanged not working or is it

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the following code and i am asumming this should work 'real time':

```
OnCheckedChanged="rbntextYes_CheckedChanged"/>
```

When i go from yes to no, nothing is happening. Is this acting normal and is my thinking wrong or is the code wrong and is label only showing after something else?

```
    protected void rbntextYes_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbltext.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: I think `OnCheckChanged` is an ASP.NET feature. Are you using that?

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry

Comment: i am reading something more now, i dont think it is possible at all like this. Only after a button click or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [`AutoPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback.aspx) property to true:

```
<!-- I assume you are using a radio button -->
<asp:RadioButton id="rbntextYes" AutoPostback="true" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="rbntextYes_CheckedChanged" />
```

Comment: thanks, just starting. Need some help. This helped out.

Comment: @user2633207 You're welcome. I'm surprised you didn't manage to search for similar questions before you asked your question. Bear in mind that you will also need to set `AutoPostBack` to true for any other control that doesn't normally make a postback, for example a CheckBox or a DropDownList's `OnSelectedIndexChanged`.